# Pyspark/Spark Event Log Access Denied Error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have tried to set up a Spark and Pyspark Environment. I have been able to scale through various errors. However, when I run my code in Anaconda Jupyter, I get the following error which is referencing access denied to the spark event file.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
    : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tmp\spark-events\local-1651494793387.inprogress (Access is denied)
```

I will appreciate it if anyone knows what settings I need to further put in place to avoid this error. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

could you show how do you instantiate the Spark context to better troubleshoot?

If you are using Spark in your own computer in standalone mode and you don't need to create or submit jobs and you want to use it only with the Python interface I will recommend you to install it by pip or conda, so you don't need to set it up.

```
# pip
pip install pyspark

# conda
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```